# Asset_url in production environment Symfony 3

Tags: css, symfony, assets, environment

I have this doubt about URLs of assetics who I generated.

On the view, this was what I did:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets
            'assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            'assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
            'assets/vendor/dist/css/*.css'
            output = 'bundles/compiled/css/app.css' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% javascripts
            'assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
            'assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
            'assets/vendor/dist/js/wow.min.js'
            'assets/vendor/dist/js/slider.js'
            'assets/vendor/dist/js/jquery.fancybox.js'
            'assets/vendor/dist/js/owl.carousel.min.js'
            'assets/vendor/dist/js/main.js'
            'assets/vendor/dist/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js' 
            output = 'bundles/compiled/js/app.js' %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

In dev environment, the app doesn't call these outputs links who `assetic:dump` generate, which is:

> bundles/compiled/css/app.css

and

> bundles/compiled/js/app.js/

both after /web folder.

In prod, I can't reach these locations. I get and 404 on
http://link.com/bundles/compiled/css/app.css for example.

So, how can I configure my `config.yml` for reach that path in `prod` environment?
This is what I have:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
cssrewrite: ~
```

**Edit:**I figured out the problem. My assetic's config was alright, the problem was in VirtualHosts file (modrewrite line, to be specific), which was only accepting ".php" extension files and web/ folder permissions.

Comment: Did you run the command `php app/console assets:install`?

Comment: @Veve Yes, before the `assetic:dump`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of using `AsseticBundle`! When you are in `prod` mode, you need to dump the asset files. Have a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files).

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod //clear the cache for prod environment
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

The result will be the concatenation of all your `css` stylesheets, in one single result file (`bundles/compiled/css/app.css`), and the concatenation of all your `js` scripts in one single result file (`bundles/compiled/js/app.js`), for the reason of `reducing the requests to the server`.
At this point, you won't be able to see, in the source of the page, all the css + js files, except those two from your `compiled/` directory.

When you are in `dev` mode, the default behavior of `AsseticBundle` is to generate all your css + js files, for debugging purposes. That is, to help you debug your code easily. So at this point you will be able to see all you css+js files, but not the two files from `compiled/` directory.

And pay attention, as `cssrewrite` must be a child of `filters`. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#installing-and-enabling-assetic) the correction you need.

Comment: I did all these instructions. But keep taking 404 on file request. In HTML of the production app, I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/b61ff27.css" />`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @gamoridev I usually add the `web/` directory in the dump console command: `$ php bin/console assetic:dump web/`, so that those paths to be valid.